# How many notifications are there on StackExchange?

Tags: discussion, stackexchange

StackExchange has the top notification bar that informs of a number of things like badges gained, for instance. The red bullet shows inbox notifications. The yellow or red boxes show validation messages.

The community moderator election has its own notification.
[image: cooking]

So, how many notifications are there and are they all needed?

Comment: The original location (UX) was correct. It belongs either on UX or possibly on MSO, but not on MUX.

Comment: @VitalyMijiritsky I don't see how this is on-topic for UX at all. The only place this MIGHT belong is MSO.

Comment: @CharlesBoyung The exact same question could be asked about Facebook, Gmail or any other site. It's a nice question on different types of notification mechanisms.